# Is there get method which not found while run web api service

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http-get

I'm creating a web api controller and implement ([HttpGet])parameterized get method with datatype class but when I run this its show 404 Not Found.
When i am implementing normal datatype like string or int its show me the answer or datatype like List still it's giving me answer but when I directly declare datatype as class like Student its show 404 not found error. I don't know why it's so. I am trying to learn web api with mvc please help me.

I am creating one simple class Student and one studentapicontroller.In my api controller, I create get method with datatype class and for testing purpose i make other get method with different datatype

Student.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace epay.Models
{
   public class student
   {
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
}
```

studentapiController :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;  
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using epay.Models;

namespace epay.Controllers
{
  public class studentapiController : ApiController
  {
    // GET api/studentapi
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }

    // GET api/studentapi/5

    {
        return "value";
    }

    // POST api/studentapi
    public void Post([FromBody]string value)
    {
    }

    // PUT api/studentapi/5
    public void Put(int id, [FromBody]string value)
    {
    }

    // DELETE api/studentapi/5
    public void Delete(int id)
    {
    }


    //POST api/studentapi/
    [HttpGet]
    public student getdetails(int id, string na)
    {
        student st = new student();
        st.id = id;
        st.name = na;
        return st;
    }

    //GET api/studentapi/getstud
    [HttpGet]
    public List<student> getstud()
    {
        List<student> lst = new List<student>();
        student st = new student();
        st.name = "manlai";
        st.id = 5;
        lst.Add(st);
        return lst;
    }
  }
```

}

I just want getdetails result or how to do if I want my method datatype as a class and I am passing parameter with my get method how to do this

Comment: How are you currently trying to call the `getdetails` endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

Make getdetails route like below because it is conflicting with get

```
[HttpGet("getdetails")]
    public student getdetails(int id, string na)
    {
        student st = new student();
        st.id = id;
        st.name = na;
        return st;
    }
```

you can call route something like this with querystring /**studentapi/getdetails?id=1&na=test**